# How to collect members' bank info?

Tags: excel, store, member, bank, info

Say I have a company where I want to make direct deposits to members' bank account. I understand that's it a really bad idea to ask them their information on the site and store it in the database.

But what If i ask our members to email us their bank info for direct deposits? I would then simply take their info and put it in excel sheet instead of storing it in the server(and delete the original email). That would be my reference point to sending the members direct deposits using my bank account. Is that legally allowed?  If not, what would be another method to request a member's bank account info to make direct deposits?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting banking account information has significant security implications and doing via email is not kosher.  But there are alternatives.
The simplest alternative is using interbank service like [Zelle](https://www.zellepay.com/) where you can send money to your members' bank accounts using just their email accounts (the one associated with their bank login).  We pay our smaller vendors this way and most get paid immediately without any transaction fees.  But this may not work for members who use smaller banks outside the network (e.g credit unions) and the service does not have sophisticated tracking or linking to invoices.

If you have international members or need a more scalable/programmatic/self-serve solution, you can consider using a payment gateway provider like paypal/braintree or [stripe-connect](https://stripe.com/connect). Stripe is especially easy to integrate with a website and instead of you collecting and maintaining banking information for your members, stripe does on your behalf.  Companies like Lyft use this to pay their drivers.  It scales and works in almost all major international locations. Downside is there are per transaction fees which get steep if you want instant payments.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I am looking for more of an international solution for payouts. I've thought about e-wallets. I can't decide which one to pick. I know about Stripe. Unfortunately stripe-connect is also limited to USA customers for custom options. So it seems like western union or e-transfer is the best to way.

Comment: Not sure where you are located - but stripe-connect does seem to support custom options in a number of countries.  Found this on-line.  Stripe Connect Custom accounts are supported for platforms located in Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Luxembourg, the Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, the United Kingdom, or the United States.

Comment: But doesn't that mean the users' whose custom accounts are created also need to be from one of those countries? Or is it only for the main person/company?

Comment: The [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect)  refers to "platforms located in" these countries - so I am assuming this is not just the user accounts, but the company.